# what does if [[ -e $filename]] means

Tags: scripts

I have this legacy Linux shell script code that I am trying to understand. I would appreciate any explanation:

```
if [[ -e $fileName]]; then
```

what I am curious about what does double-bracket mean?

Comment: see [What is the difference between test, [ and [[](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/031)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Short answer**: it's telling the shell to check into the existence of  `$filename` to know whether to choose the `then` or `else` statement.

Before the if-statement can be evaluated, the condition needs to be tested -- is it true or is it false? Here, `[[ ]]` denotes a boolean variable whose value depends on the expression within. Traditionally, `[ ]` was the bash syntax to issue `test` command, returning the value of the expression, regardless of type and in any context. Newer versions of bash adopted `[[ ]]` as a keyword exclusively for if-statements. I'd imagine this prevents type errors, or something.